# Defining the static and void keywords in Java

Tags: java, static, void

I am currently studying for my Java final and on a practice exam am asked to define both the static and void keywords, I just wanted to know if any of you smart lads had anything you would tweak or add to my answers, which are as follows:

> **What does the static keyword mean?**
>   Static variables and methods belong to a whole class, not to an object. Static methods can be invoked without using any object. Only one instance of a static field exists.
>
> **What does the void keyword mean?**
>   Void indicates that a method does not return anything.

Thanks in advance for any help, you guys are great.

Comment: If you're just looking for definitions of those terms, surely the Java documentation has those?

Comment: @AlexQuilliam thanks! I felt that my void answer looks skimpy compared to static but couldn't really decide on anything else.

Comment: @David I did go to Oracle but I found their definition of the void class in Java, not the specific keyword. The definition of the class was not of much help, either.

Comment: You should be looking at the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html). You've missed two entire meanings of `static`.